# Hide thumbnail of Backend file uploader

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml

I am using magento's default file uploader in my custom modules. How can I hide the image thumbnail shown in image below?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using your custom module for displaying system configuration then change in your system.xml. Replace image with file in your  `<frontend_type>file</frontend_type>` field.

Comment: I did the same just before. Yes. Its the exact method. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is best done with CSS. Find the ID of the `<tr>` tag your `system > configuration` field is in and then add the following CSS to either your own custom stylesheet or a general stylesheet

```
#row_custom_field img { display: none; }
```